# Regex pattern for matching "-" character but only if there are other word characters present

Tags: python, regex

I have a set of entries for matching. One pattern, that I have already written, matches strings that consist of "-" only, e.g.:

```
----
---
--------
```

The regex code for matching these is

```
r"^[-]+$"
```

Now I need to match strings that contain "-" character, but only if there are other word characters in the string, e.g.:

```
---vsgvrf-sgwfwrgfs---
-----hwvchwbfk
bfcbewubf------
-efefe-ege-
-gdiwen
```

Etc. I have tried next patterns, but they do not work and skip some of the string:

```
r"(\w[^-])+-+(\w[^-])*"
r"\w[^-]+-+\w[^-]+|-+\w[^-]+|\w[^-]+-+"
```

Could somebody help me here?

Comment: So any string that contains at least one `-` and at least one "word character"?

Comment: Yes! But the important part is that it doesn't match `-`only strings. I am struggling with including strings like `--gggg` or `----gggg`

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex (word char before or after a dash):

```
r'(-\w|\w-)'
```

Answer (score 2):

If hyphen and `\w` both are required, how about:

```
^(?:-+\w|\w+-)[\w-]*$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YjosB3/1)

---

If just `\w` is required with an optional amount of hyphens and *word characters*:

```
^-*\w[-\w]*$
```

[Another demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gTjwXw/1) (to me your question reads like this would suffice)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `((?:\w+-+|-+\w+)+\w*-*)`.

```
import re
m = re.compile(r'((?:\w+-+|-+\w+)+\w*-*)')
lines = ['-Before', '-Before-Middle', 'Middle-After-', 'After-', '--All--Three--', 'No Match', '-', '--', '---']
for line in lines:
    if m.match(line):
        print(m.match(line).groups())
```

Output:

```
('-Before',)
('-Before-Middle',)
('Middle-After-',)
('After-',)
('--All--Three--',)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with a negative lookahead asserting not only word characters:

```
^(?!\w+$)-*\w[\w-]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EErG8C/1)